Non-enumerability of total recursive functions
To characterize all effectively calculable functions, we would
like to produce a list $\mathcal{C} = \left\{ f_n \right\}_{n \in \omega} $ (with $\omega = \mathbb{N} + \{0\}$)
such that:

The list includes all and only algorithmically computable functions
There is an efective listing of said list, i.e. an algorithmically computable function $g(n, x) = f_n(x)$.
Every $f_n$ is total.

The following argument is given to show that such listing does not exist in the book Turing computability:

Define the diagonal function $h(x) = g(x, x) + 1$. Since $g$ is computable, so is $h$. However, $h \not\in \mathcal{C}$ because $h(x) \neq f_x(x)$.

I agree that $f_x(x) + 1 = h(x) \neq f_x(x)$. However, I do not see how this entails $h \not\in \mathcal{C}$, since we only require that
$h(x)$ be $f_n(x)$ for some $n$ (not necessarily $n = x$).
Any help in understanding this is much appreciated.

This is almost certainly a duplicate, but assume $h \in \mathcal{C}$; then there is $x$ such that $h = f_x$, hence $h(x) = f_x(x)$, a contradiction.

Does it help to note that "since we only require that
$h(x)$ be $f_n(x)$ for some $n$" SHOULD BE "since we only require that
$h$ be $f_n$ for some $n$"? The former is a requirement about two specific positive integers, whereas the latter is a requirement about two specific functions defined on the positive integers.
